# SQL where in with lists in Oracle PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, where-clause, where-in

I have the following "table1" :

```
NAME     JOB    

Mary     pilot, astronaut, cook
John     astronaut, biker
Michael  rider
Rita     teacher, doctor
```

I want to select all people who are an astronaut OR a doctor. It should return Mary, John and Rita.

I currently have:

```
select name from table1 
where 'astronaut,doctor' in (select regexp_substr(table1.job,'[^'',]+', 1, level) 
     from dual
     connect by regexp_substr(table1.job, '[^'',]+', 1, level) is not null)
```

However, I don't want to compare the whole string on the left-hand side, instead I want to iterate through it.

Note: I'm getting the left-hand argument as an input argument, so it must be parsed inside the sql.

Comment: MSSQL: `select * from @temp
where JOB like '%doctor%' OR JOB like '%astronaut%'`

Comment: Both MS SQL Server and Oracle tags? How come?

Comment: Is it really required that the two jobs you're looking for a provided in a single value? Would a clause of the form `where ... or ....` (like tinka proposed) work as well?

Comment: @tinka@Codo as I said, I can't separate the input arguments as '%doctor%' and '%astronaut%'. It needs to be a long string, delimited inside by commas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should fix your data format.  You are trying to store lists in a column, and that is a bad idea.  You should be using a junction table rather than delimited values.

Sometimes, we are stuck with other people's bad design decisions.  Oracle does have powerful regular expression operators.  This does allow:

```
select name, job
from table1
where regexp_like(job, replace('astronaut,doctor', ',', '|');
```